# What is the default WCF Binding?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I've been struggling for a few days with [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186663/cant-send-wcf-service-request-as-soapxml), learning a lot of things on bindings in the process.
One thing puzzles me, though: various links (see [this](http://leowu70.blogspot.com/2010/09/wcf-error-request-failed-with-http.html) or [that](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/HttpBinding.aspx) for example) explicitly state "By default, WCF project is created using WsHttpBinding", but that's not what I see.
This is what I do:

1. Open Visual Studio 2010 and choose New Project / Visual C# / WCF Service Application
2. Don't touch anything inside the code, set a local IIS Url for the service (say http://localhost/WcfService7)
3. Open soapUI and choose File / New Soap UI Project / enter the url of the newly created wsdl: http://localhost/WcfService7/Service1.svc?wsdl, not touching any other option
4. Interface properties: SOAP Version = SOAP 1.1, Binding = "BasicHttpBinding_IService1" (even though it's just a name, it's a hell of a hint)
5. Open Altova XmlSpy and choose SOAP / Create new SOAP Request / enter the url of the wsdl / select any operation
6. SOAP / Change SOAP Request parameters / Ensure that "Send as SOAP+XML (SOAP 1.2)" is checked
7. SOAP / Send request to server:  i get the errors

   HTTP error: could not POST file ‘/WcfService7/Service1.svc’ on server ’localhost’ (415)

   Error sending the soap data to ‘http://localhost/WcfService7/Service1.svc’ HTTP error: could not POST file ‘/WcfService7/Service1.svc’ on server ’10.51.0.108’ (415)

Any explanations? Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When hosting WCF service in IIS (using WCF Service application project template) with default .svc file (without changing its service host factory) the default binding is `basicHttpBinding`. If you want to change default binding to `wsHttpBinding` you must use:

```
<protocolMapping>
    <add scheme="http" binding="wsHttpBinding"/>
</protocolMapping>
```

In your service's configuration file but it will not solve your problem because you don't need `wsHttpBinding` and as I remember Altova XmlSpy is not able to send valid request for `wsHttpBinding` because it supports only basic SOAP stack without WS-* protocols.

Answer (score 2):

The default is basichttpbinding using SOAP 1.1.

That is why you get an error sending it as SOAP 1.2.